# Need to add Label on UIView programatically based on some conditions using swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, constraints, uilabel

I am working on a canvas view where I am trying to add image to a UIView and a text to a UIView, on satisfying some conditions.

The issue is, I am not able to add label to my UIView after satisfying the required condition. I tried this code separately without any functions and conditions and it is working fine. But if I try and run it as given below it doesn't show me the label on the UIView.
[Note- The code here is working fine for imageView.]

I tried various constraint combinations like, centerX, centerY, width, height or leading, trailing, top, bottom. But nothing is working. Please help.

My code is as below: -

```
class CanvasViewController: UIViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        createCanvasOnAspectRatio()
    }

func createCanvasOnAspectRatio() {
        let View1: UIView = {
            let viewView = UIView()
            viewView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            viewView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            print(UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "backgroundColourSelected"))
            if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "backgroundColourSelected") {
                viewView.backgroundColor = self.viewColor
            }else {
                viewView.backgroundColor = .white
            }
            viewView.clipsToBounds = true
            return viewView
        }()
        self.canvasView.addSubview(View1)
        
        View1.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: canvasView.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        View1.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: canvasView.centerYAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        View1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: canvasView.widthAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        View1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: canvasView.widthAnchor, multiplier: aspectRatio).isActive = true
        
        if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "imageSelectedFromGallexy") == true {
            for item in 0..<self.imagesForGallery.count {
                let image = imagesForGallery[item]
                let image_View: UIImageView = {
                    let imageV = UIImageView()
                    imageV.image = image
                    imageV.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
                    imageV.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                    imageV.clipsToBounds = true
                    return imageV
                }()
                
                View1.addSubview(image_View)
                image_View.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: View1.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
                image_View.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: View1.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
                image_View.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: View1.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
                image_View.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: View1.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            }
        }
        
        if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "addTextToCanvas") == true {
            
            let labelTextView: UILabel = {
                let labelView = UILabel()
                //labelView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 50.0, height: 30.0)
                labelView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                labelView.textColor = .green
                labelView.text = "Hello"
                labelView.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Medium", size: 15.0)
                labelView.textAlignment = .center
                // labelView.clipsToBounds = true
                return labelView
            }()
            
            View1.addSubview(labelTextView)
            
            labelTextView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: View1.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            labelTextView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: View1.centerYAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            labelTextView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: View1.widthAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            labelTextView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: View1.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true
            
            UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "addTextToCanvas")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks fine, can you show us kinda screenshot of layout you get with this code? May be the problem is with your User defaults stuff - you are setting addTextToCanvas to false. Thats why the code, that adds label to View1 is not triggering.

Comment: Yes, have you set breakpoints to confirm the code is executing the way you think it is?  Have you debugged the view hierarchy to see what views and constraints have been added?

Comment: Thanks for your input @Mikhail Vasilev, I found that the aspect ration value that comes in from other view is getting set to 'nil', if I execute the textView code from where I am getting a text for my label. I fixed that and now it is working fine. Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you @Paulw11, I tried the above changes from my end and it worked.